# In Swift, how do you execute one query to Parse before another on PFQueryTableViewController?

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to do two queries to Parse in my PFQueryTableViewController. I am trying to do one query to obtain all of the objects relating to the currentUser and then place those objects into an array. After the array is filled with its objects, I would like to do another query from

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery { }.
```

This second query will use the objects from the array that was created from the first query, in order to retrieve objects of its own.

I don't know how to make the first query execute before the second. As of right now, the second query will execute before the first one before it has a chance to fill the array and as a result messes up the query for the second one. The following is what i have for my code at this point.

```
class PFNewsFeedTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

var leadersArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    leadersArray.removeAllObjects()

    var findLeaders = PFQuery(className: "Follow")

    findLeaders.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    findLeaders.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    findLeaders.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        //If no error
        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) leaders.")

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    self.leadersArray.addObject(object.objectForKey("leader")!)

                }

            }

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        self.queryForTable()
    }

}



override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    var findContent = PFQuery(className: "Content")
    findContent.whereKey("user", containedIn: self.leadersArray as [AnyObject])
    findContent.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    return findContent
}    

}
```

Is there a way to determine the order in which these queries get executed? Any help to this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Let me first start by saying that it does sound like you should try to maybe rethink your data model, as executing two queries in succession like this is often a sign of focusing too much on traditional data modeling rather than the more pragmatic nosql-style of modeling where you (especially for mobile apps) should model for queries rather than normalisation.

If you were to solve your case like you said, you can employ the [Bolts framework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC). No need to install this, as this is already installed as part of Parse (which uses Bolts behind the scenes).

It could then look something like this (just a quick write-up. Will probably not work out of the box, but you should be able to make it fit):

```
var findLeaders = PFQuery(className: "Follow")
findLeaders.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
findLeaders.orderByDescending("createdAt")
findLeaders.findObjectsInBackground().continueWithBlock {
    (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in

    //If no error
    if task.error != nil {
        print("Something went wrong...")
    } else {
        // Do something with the found objects
        if let objects = task.result as? [PFObject] {
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) leaders.")

            for object in objects {
                self.leadersArray.addObject(object.objectForKey("leader")!)
            }
        }
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    self.queryForTable()
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you for pointing out the pragmatic approach to me. I didn't realize I was focusing on traditional data modeling as I am new to programming. When I tweaked my code however, I am getting an error saying "Missing return in a closure expected to return 'AnyObject!' " Do you know why this might be?

Comment: If you are using BFTask, you define what the block will return. In my example, the block returns AnyObject!. If you don't need to return anything there, I think you can replace AnyObject! with Void

Comment: No, that won't work. Leave AnyObject! and then right before the closing bracket, return nil. I've updated my example.

Comment: I dont get any errors now but the content doesnt show up in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem and it looks like this

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    var findLeaders = PFQuery(className: "Follow")
    findLeaders.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    findLeaders.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    var findContent = PFQuery(className: "Content")
    findContent.whereKey("user", matchesKey: "leader", inQuery: findLeaders)
    findContent.orderByDescending("createdAt")


    return findContent
}
```

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your need. You wrote you needed to first perform one query and then another. You are now using findLeaders as an inner query in findContent, which is of course fine. If, though, you needed to actually perform the second query after having handled the first, then you would have to use something like I suggested, or else you would have to perform both queries on the main thread (synchronously), which would not work. I'm sorry I misunderstood your question.

Comment: OK thats good to know for the future and I appreciate your help.