# PFQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock not getting called?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, pfquery

```
let userQuery = PFUser.query()
userQuery!.whereKey("username", equalTo: userUsername)
userQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (result:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) in
    currentProfilePageUser = result![0] as! PFUser
 })
```

This is my code. I'm trying to get a `PFUser` with only the username. But, I added breakpoints inside `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` and discovered that it is not getting called. Therefore, I cannot receive my data. Why isn't `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` getting called?

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Follow")
    query.whereKey("followFrom", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    query.whereKey("followingTo", equalTo: currentProfilePageUser)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) in
        if result == nil{
            print("currentuser is not following this user")
            self.followButtonTitle.setTitle("Follow", forState: .Normal)
        }else{
            print("currentuser is follwing this user")
            self.followButtonTitle.setTitle("Unfollow", forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
```

For some really weird reason, the first `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` works now, but this other one doesn't get called. This is very weird.

Comment: It is probably being called, but since it is "inBackground" this means that it is called on a background thread. Try testing for error and add a print statement for them both. You should see that at least one of them are called then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if you get a print in your console:

```
let userQuery = PFUser.query()
userQuery!.whereKey("username", equalTo: userUsername)
userQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (result:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) in
    if(error == nil){
        print("Success!")
    } else {
        print("Failed with error \(error)")
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this runs. I put a breakpoint in here and it hits the breakpoint. I really don't get why this `findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` runs but some don't.....

Comment: oh wow and now command+z switched to the old code and it runs perfectly. This is so weird.

Comment: this findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock works now, but my other one still doesn't work.

Comment: I changed my 2nd `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` into this code too but it doesn't get called and nothing runs.

Comment: now it all gets called.... I basically just deleted and command+z my code and it all gets called. omg this is so weird

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd query i posted above requires the first query's results. For some reason, the 2nd query runs first, then the first regardless of the order of my code. My fix was to put the 2nd query inside `viewDidAppear`, putting it in `viewWillAppear` won't even work.

Comment: This is not the way to solve your issue. You're dealing with basic concurrency issues. If you have 2 queries where the second needs data from the first, you have two choices: running synchronous queries (bad) or making sure your second query does not trigger before the first has completed. You can easily accomplish this by using the Bolts Framework. Check this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161271/in-swift-how-do-you-execute-one-query-to-parse-before-another-on-pfquerytablevi/35162052#35162052